# How do you get a border on TF2?

Tags: team-fortress-2, macos

I have a Mac Pro and I would like to idle on TF2. The problem is that there is no toolbar so I can't get out of TF2 unless I disconnect from the server I'm on and I quit TF2.
I would like to know how to get the border/toolbar on the window.

Comment: I don't have much experience on macs, but can't you just command+tab to the desktop like on windows?

Comment: Oh, wow! I didn't remember to do that. Works! Though it didn't show the little switching animation, so i guess valve tried to prevent idling and switching to different windows.

Answer (score 2):

To get TF2 in a window:

1. From the main menu, click **Options** and then the **Video** tab.
2. Change the **Display mode** setting to **Run in a window**.
3. You will probably also want to set the **Resolution** (which will now control the window size) to something smaller than your actual screen size so that the window fits nicely.
4. Click **OK** or **Apply**.

As noted in comments, you can also use Command-Tab to switch away and leave TF2 running in the background, instead of using windowed mode.

(Information that might be useful context for curious readers from other platforms: There are about three different ways of implementing full-screen on Mac OS X, and a lot of games use an older one that defaults to leaving Command-Tab non-functional. Luckily, TF2 does support it.)

Answer (score 1):

Add `-windowed -noborder` to steam startup options.

But don't try to idle. it doesn't work anymore.